# Tenda N301 unresponsive as a Universal Repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge, repeater

I have two routers:

1 **Tenda TE-D303:** Primary Router; Access to internet using WAN

2 **Tenda N301:** Secondary Router; To be used as a Range Extender

Problem is that as soon as I set N301 as a Universal Repeater, it works for maybe like 30sec, after which it becomes unresponsive. Opening its page shows 'connection timed out' and any computer connected to its secondary default network doesn't get an IP address (checked using ipconfig)

Please Help.

Comment: If you connect to N301 using ethernet cable does it work?

Comment: If you mean connecting a PC to N301 after setting it up as a repeater, then no, the problem remains the same.
Connecting both the routers on the other hand, I need your help.
Please note that it is not feasible for me to install it with a wired connection because of the placement of the routers.

Comment: Then do as what my comment says and report the results

Comment: LAN cable from normal port of D303 to normal port of N301:

Comment: LAN cable from normal port of D303 to normal port of N301(Factory Settings). Its IP changed from default 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.1.50, with DHCP range of 1-150:
I can access the internet through N301's default hosted network.
All the devices show up on D303's DHCP list.
Universal repeater settings don't take any effect until I remove the LAN cable. If it were to, Wi-fi analyzer (android) would show two networks with the same SSID (which in my case is HomeNet).
Once again, on removing the LAN cable, the Universal Router settings take effect and the above problems happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Slogged for several hours with technical support.
His supervisor finally found the answer.

**The secondary network of N301 needs to have the same SSID, protection, and password in order to work like a charm**.
All the while connected to a PC on LAN until set up.

Nowhere on the detailed manual and Tenda YouTube Channel it was said.
Sorry to trouble everyone.

Comment: **No need to fiddle with primary router.** Can also extend WPA2 network without any problem,